# python compare list of dicts with list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

I have a list of dicts and list of tuples. List of dicts is sort of lookup table. Based on pairs I have to get the keys and for non-matches I need to get 'NA' key.

e.g

```
lookup_table = [
        {"L" : (148, -1) },
        {"D" : (148,440) },
        {"N1" : (148,441)},
        {"C" : (148,443) }]

data= [(10,10),(15,15),(148,-1) ,(148,440),(148,443)]
```

my result should be

```
res = ['NA': (10,10), 'NA': (15,15),"L" : (148, -1),"D" : (148,440),"C" : (148,443) ]
```

I know how to get the matches but I am struggling with the 'NA's

Is this kind of approach even possible with python since I have multiple keys with the same name?

Thank you

Comment: You showed your expected result. What is the actual result that you are getting with your code?

Comment: No it is not. Your final creation `res` is not even a valid Python object. Actually, you seem to be struggling with types from the get go. Why is `lookup_table` a list of dictionaries and not a single dictionary?

Comment: update your question to show a proper/valid final result

Comment: Like I wrote - I am searching for the best solution - If you recommend having a dict for lookup table so be it. also for result - if It needs to be a list of dict I will change it  - just looking for the best option. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

NA is a key of your dictionary, it must be unique value. So, you better use list as result. Something like `res = [['N/A', (10,10)],['L', (148, -1)]]`

Answer (score 0):

Your `res` shows a list. However, it seems like you want to have a `dictionary` instead.

```
res = ['NA': (10,10), 'NA': (15,15),"L" : (148, -1),"D" : (148,440),"C" : (148,443) ]
```

So you might try to do this instead:

```
res = { 'NA': (10,10), 'NA': (15,15),"L" : (148, -1),"D" : (148,440),"C" : (148,443) }
```

However, this will still be invalid because `'NA'` is a `key` and it should be unique. So what you should do instead is to have a `list of dictionaries`, a `list of tuples`, or a `list of lists`.

```
# List of Dictionaries:
res = [{'NA': (10,10)}, {'NA': (15,15}), {'L' : (148, -1)}, {'D' : (148,440)},{'C' : (148,443)} ]

# List of Tuples
res = [('NA', (10,10)), ('NA', (15,15)),('L', (148, -1)), ('D', (148,440)), ('C', (148,443)) ]

# List of Lists
res = [['NA', (10,10)], ['NA', (15,15)], ['L', (148, -1)], ['D', (148,440)], ['C', (148,443)]]
```

I am not sure though which one fits best in what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

So using some of your suggestions solved it

first I turned my lookup table into list of lists. Followed by the code

```
new_data_woshi = []
#add 'NA' to all in my data list of tuples
for rec in data_woshi:
    new_data_woshi.append(['NA', rec])

#go trough loopkup if there is a match replace the current element
for rec in new_data_woshi:
    for a in lookup_table:
        if rec[1] == a[1]:
            rec[0] = a[0]
```